# Faced BlueJ Java questions

Tags: java, bluej

"What is the format of the first line of a method?"
It is depends on the developer design right? But somehow, but how am I to write a proper answer other than mine.

"How can you view javadoc for a class?"
This is the most difficult question that i can't find the solution. Please guide on this.

Comment: In order to view the javadoc of your class use the combo-box at the right side of the editor toolbar. It comes with the default "Source Code" selection. Choose "Documentation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the format of the first line of a method?

The first line of a method consists of modifiers such as `public` or `private`, then the return type, the method name, the parameter list and optionally a `throws` clause with exception types that the method might throw.

See [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials for a detailed explanation.

> How can you view javadoc for a class?

You can find the [Javadoc online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Most IDEs have a built-in capability to view the Javadoc. Check the [BlueJ documentation](http://www.bluej.org/doc/documentation.html).

Comment: I though the first line of the method is referring the every first line code execution? LOL!